# How do i add a custom made TinyMCE form element to my Zend Project?

Tags: forms, zend-framework, tinymce

I have been working with Zend for a few months now and am at a stage where i'd like to add some fields to my form using TinyMce. What i want to achieve is to be able to just create a form extending Zend_form and just be able to say

$element = new TinyMce_Form_Element_Editor('element');

But i just do not have a single clue on how to achieve this. I have of course been looking around before asking this question and most sources just point me towards [this site.](http://juriansluiman.nl/en/article/100/improved-tinymce-solution-for-the-zend-framework#heading1)
Wich seems to be aimed at people with alot of experiance with Zend. 2 months in it's not a big surprise i am not at the level this might have been intended for as i have tried following the instrucutions given and creating the file setup as shown by in the svn repositiry create by the writer of this article.

Aside from heading from one error into another i also do not uderstand what the code is doing exactly, i just have a vague guess at best when i run trough it.

Is there any kind of easy to follow simple tutorial explaining how to enable tinymce in a Zend Form?

Any advice or tips on how to achieve my goal will be well appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not best solution but you may find it useful:

```
class My_Form_Element_Tinymce extends Zend_Form_Element_Textarea
{
    /**
     * Element CSS class name
     * @var string 
     */
    protected $class = 'tinyMCE';

    public function init() 
    {
        $this->getView()->headScript()->appendFile('path/to/tinymce.js');
        $this->getView()->headScript()->appendFile('path/to/tinymce_config.js');
    }
}
```

and in your `tinymce_config.js` add selector for `tinyMCE` class name

`tinymce_config.js` is your tinyMCE configuration file if you never used tinyMCE goto http://tinymce.com and you will find many examples with what you need.

Comment: I tried your sugestion and i come across 2 problems. 

Firstly, I cannot find the file tinymce_config.js you mention. Is this a config file i have to setup myself? If so, how exactly?

Second I commented out the tinymce_config line temporarely and tried to work with it this way and i now recieve the following error :

`Call to a member function appendScript() on a non-object`

Comment: try with `$this->getView()` (updated answer) seems you didn't set view. With tinymce config you will have to look into examples or documentation of tinymce at http://tinymce.com/

Comment: The problem i keep getting stuck at is the fact i cannot append the script on a view object. I used getView wich indeed getsthe view object however the view object doesn't have a method called `appendScript($path);` It returns the error `Plugin by name 'AppendScript' was not found in the registry`

I should note i am working with Zend Framework version 1.11.11

Comment: After some trial and error i've gotten it to work! Thanks alot!